# hibernate iterating over all rows in a table that meet a multi-table where join

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hiberante.  Need to be pointed in right direction.

I need iterate over all records in table "target_table" where there are additional constraints based on other tables

the sql providing the desired data records is

```
select target_table.id, .... 
  from  person,  
        target_table, 
        another_table 
 where person.id = target_table.person_Id 
   and target_table.dropEventId = another_table.id 
   and another_table.to_Vendor_Timestamp < to_date('Jul 29 2012','MON dd YYYY') 
   and person.identifyer = 'foobar';
```

Not sure what the best way of getting those records.  can someone recommend the proper way?
At the moment I am starting to thing 
something along the lines of

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TargetTable.class);
Criteria personCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("person");
personCriteria.add(Restriction.equal("idenifyier",identifyier);
Criteria anotherTableConstriant = constriant.add("another_table");
anotherTableConstraint.add(Restriction.lessthan("toVendorTimeStamp", someDateObject);
```

but how do I get the rest of the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Never think Hibernate as something like "another way of using SQL/DB".  You should always make sure that you have proper entities, and relationship between entities.

It seems that from your example, you should have a relationship of Target->Another (called dropEvent), and Target->Person (assume it is person).

The HQL is simply something like

```
from Target t
where t.person.identifier = :someId
  and t.dropEvent.vendorTimeStamp < :someTime
```

If you find yourselves still always think of joining tables etc, it is most likely that you are not using Hibernate properly.  In such case, I find Hibernate is not going to help you.  Consider using iBatis if your app is designed in such a DB-centric mindset.

Comment: Table target has a column for person_id which is a foreign key to the person table.  the person record has a column identifyier.   My where clause where t.person.identifier when executed gives me Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: person of: com.....T   Any idea what would cause that, and how to move through this road block?

Comment: Adrian you are right on the query. "target_table.dropEventId" really should be "target_table.another_table_id = another_table.id"

Comment: Have u tried to understand what I said in the reply? You are precisely those kind of people that think HQL/Hibernate being just another form of SQL/ RDBMS. Have u tried to get your object design and OR Mapping right?